# PHP, DOM, XML parsing

Tags: php, xml, dom, removechild

I'm new to PHP and the whole world of DOM and XML Parsing, but here I have stumbled onto this one. If one removes a child node and then calls `hasChildNodes()` on the parent node, it would return a non-zero number. However if we set the `preserveWhiteSpace` to `FALSE`, this problem does not arise. So my question is how can we make `hasChildNodes()` return 0 after calling `removeChild` (assuming there is just one child) while preserving white space and formatting?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really, you'd have to walk the child nodes and filter out the ones you don't care about (text nodes in this case).

In pseudo-code:

```
children = node->getChildren();

array_filter(children, function (element) {
    return element->isTextNode() && empty(trim(element->getText()));
});
```